# How to execute a cmd command using QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting to execute a cmd command using

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd /c net stop \"MyService\"");
```

This does not seem to stop the service. However, if I run it from start >> run, it works.

Comment: Try startDetached("cmd", QStringList() << "/c" << "net" << "stop" << "MyService"); and the same with << "\"MyService\"". For further debugging, don't use startDetached but start and connect to the QProcess instance's finished() and error() signals.

Comment: Here is what i tried `QProcess::startDetached("cmd.exe ", QStringList() << " /c " << " net " << " stop " << " \"MyService\"");` and it isnt working

Comment: @MistyD: Try it without all the extra spaces, just like Frank suggested.

Comment: I tried it - unfortunatly it does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QProcess::startDetached will take the first parameter as the command to execute and the following parameters, delimited by a space, will be interpreted as separate arguments to the command.

Therefore, in this case: -

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd /c net stop \"MyService\"");
```

The function sees **cmd** as the command and passes /c, net, stop and "MyService" as arguments to cmd. However, other than /c, the others are parsed separately and are not valid arguments.

What you need to do is use quotes around the "net stop \"MyService\" to pass it as a single argument, so that would give you: -

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd /c \"net stop \"MyService\"\"");
```

Alternatively, using the string list you could use: -

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd", QStringList() << "/c" << "net stop \"MyService\"");
```

Comment: The second example should read: `QProcess::startDetached("cmd /c \"net stop \\\"MyService\\\"\"");` (mind the extra escapes inside the parameter string)

Comment: Not working for me and not required. In a `mkdir` example, this is enough:
`proc.start("cmd /c mkdir \"c:/temp/foo bar9\"")`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66145732/2398993)