# calling Qprocess with arguments containing spaces - Windows

Tags: windows, qt, qprocess

I am trying to call an executable with `qprocess` and pass some arguments which might (and most probably will) contain spaces (not all of them).
The executable is a `python` script that has been packaged with `Py2exe`. The `python` script uses `optparse` to parse the arguments.

If I call the `py2exe.exe` in `cmd.exe` the call is like this:

```
pythonExecutable.exe -aarg_a -barg_b -c"path with spaces" -darg_d
```

A call like this will be successful.

I want to do this through a `Qt` application using `Qprocess`, but I can't find a way to do it because `Qprocess` will strip any quotes(`""`) leaving the arguments broken wherever spaces appear.

I seem to be missing something, can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a cmd command using QProcess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596104/how-to-execute-a-cmd-command-using-qprocess)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

that won't be much of an issue if u use the QProcess in a more proper way

```
QString program = "pythonExecutable.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments <<"-aarg_a"<< "-barg_b"<< "-c\"path with spaces\""<< "-darg_d";

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

normaly when u have arguments with space and do't need a " symbol

you just have to pass the argument in a **QStringList**

```
QString program = "pythonExecutable.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments <<"a"<< "path with spaces";

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

this program is a modified version of example program listed in the Qt docs [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)